# FeatureClass.Search freeze

Tags: arcobjects, c#, oracle-dbms, add-in

ArcMap add-in is freezing on .Search() by spatial filter. 
Here is my code, for ArcMap add-in 10.3 version. When I used it with Oracle databases, happens only on one instance, works perfectly with others. No error is thrown, it just waits there. Do you have any idea why this may be happening?

```
        IGeometry osakaGeometry = (IGeometry)point; //point - IPoint
        // Use the ITopologicalOperator interface to create a buffer.
        ITopologicalOperator topoOperator = (ITopologicalOperator)osakaGeometry;
        IGeometry buffer = topoOperator.Buffer(buffersize);


        List<IFeature> retVal = new List<IFeature>();
        ISpatialFilter spatialFilter = new SpatialFilterClass();
        spatialFilter.Geometry = buffer;//queryGeometry;
        spatialFilter.SpatialRel = reltype;//esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelTouches;
        spatialFilter.SubFields = "*";
        spatialFilter.WhereClause = "1=1";

        foreach (IFeatureLayer fl in ToSelectLayers)
        {
            IFeatureCursor fcursor = fl.FeatureClass.Search(spatialFilter, false);
```

...
Not: I tried buffer size from 0.003 to 1. Apparently it is not the issue.

Comment: inpoint  is IPoint, so I look for a features in ToSelectLayers located at %buffer% distance from inpoint.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.

Comment: well, I think it is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: Corrected what I could. So don't agree. Actually the problem is defined in the header. Question is about details + text before code kinda gives an idea.

Comment: Have you tried running an equivalent spatial query directly on the Oracle server instead of through Arc?

Comment: Are you trying to find the features *within a distance* from point? I usually use esriSpatialRelEnum.esriSpatialRelIntersects and omit SubFields and WhereClause - in both cases you've specified a default value in a different way, so you can just comment out those lines. What are the spatial references of the feature layers? I would buffer.project(fl.SpatialReference) then set spatialFilter.Geometry = buffer on each iteration, it could be that a difference in spatial reference between fl and spatialFilter.Geometry is causing the freeze.

Comment: @danielm, Query in Oracle SqlDeveloper works fine, though can't test it in bulk way.

Comment: @MichaelStimson, Lambert/WGS84 both for point and layers.  There is a mistake in SpatialRel, since it is parametric as part of a function, It is passed as esriSpatialRelIntersects.

Comment: This might be too complex an issue; in SDE/PostGIS selections work fine up until a limit (not sure on numbers), simple selections can be performed but more complex selections stall if the connected username doesn't have a schema matching their username... Oracle may be different. Try exporting the table to file geodatabase, select from that and see if the selection is still failing, if it does not then it's most likely an Oracle tuning issue.